# Variable doesn't exist in current context in for loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop

This is probably something painfully obvious and will probably treat me to a portion of down-votes but... Visual Studio tells me that `int i` doesn't exist in the current context in the `if/else` statement . What is going on here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LongSequence
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int numberToPrint;

            for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++);
            {  
                if (i % 2 == 0)

                    numberToPrint = i;
                else 
                    numberToPrint = i *(-1);
                Console.WriteLine(numberToPrint);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `;` from the end of the `for`statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++);
```

This loop doesn't have body because of the `;`. So it's not doing anything at all.
So, your other code is treated as another statement,which is outside the scope of the loop, in which the variable `i` is created.

Answer (score 1):

[`For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop should not have a termination, In your code, it will give an error because it terminates there.So value of i is not defined after that, Change it like below

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
     if (i % 2 == 0)
         numberToPrint = i;
     else 
         numberToPrint = i *(-1);
         Console.WriteLine(numberToPrint);
     }
```